# PdfReader.unethicalreading = true; not working

Tags: c#, itext

We have an interface that allows users to send back copies of the receipts to our customers. The user feeds in up to a five or so PDFs and they all get merged using itextsharp's (v5.5.13.1) PdfReader.

Unfortunately some users somehow password-protect a file or two here and there... I want to avoid the issue of needing to trust the user to supply us with unprotected files.

Relevant code

```
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
PdfReader reader = null;

foreach(string pdf in pdfs)
{
   reader = new PdfReader(pdf);//iTextSharp.text.exceptions.BadPasswordException : 'Bad user password'
}
```

If there are no password-protected files, the merge goes off without a hitch. Otherwise when it comes to the offending file, the above will throw at the line with the thrown exception.

From what I understood **unethicalreading** was all that was needed. I even tried to assign it immediately before the line that throws but it gives me the same result.

Does this flag work on C# since most of the help I see online for this library is written for Java (normal, I know, but I wonder if this part of the library has been properly ported)?

Comment: To answer your question about porting. Feel free to compare https://github.com/itext/itextpdf and https://github.com/itext/itextsharp - the team that did the porting, took great care to make sure that functionality is identical.

Comment: It's not a question about porting. Either I made a mistake in my code, which was mostly copied from examples I saw on the web, the C# version requirement is not the same as the Java requirement, something about how the Java version works isn't the same as the C# version, or ...?

Comment: And I looked at the code in both - everything seems good to me - so something about my use of the flag is erroneous or some other mysterious reason is keeping it from working.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you Alex, unfortunately I am unable to answer that part of your question.

Comment: @AlexInParis Can you provide example files for which that fails? There are two situations in which your approach will fail in spite of `unethicalreading` - (1) both the owner password and the user password of the PDF are not empty; in that case iText needs a password to open the file; (2) an encryption algorithm is used iText does not know; you use iText 5 which has not been supported anymore for a number of years (except for a security patch here or there), so that situation might occur for newer PDF encryption algorithms. But maybe your case is not one of these two cases...